# Null response in await api

Tags: flutter, dart

This print('response>>>>>>'); print(response); is NULL
print ("api") - this return is OK

In Api.dart

> Future list(arguments) async {Dio dio = new Dio();
>         try {
>           var arg = arguments;
>           String refreshToken = token;
>           dio.options.baseUrl = serverUrl + "/test/" + arg.toString();
>           dio.options.responseType = ResponseType.json;
>
> ```
>     Response response = await dio.get(
>         "${dio.options.baseUrl}",
>         options: Options(
>             headers: {
>               'Authorization': "Bearer $refreshToken",
>               'Content-Type': "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
>               'Accept': "gzip"
>             }
>         )
>     );
>       print ("api");
>       print(response.data);
>     return await response.data;
>   } catch (e) {
>     print(e);
>   }
> ```

myclass.dart

```
cl
```

> ass Page extends StatefulWidget {
>         @override
>         PageState createState() => PageState();
>       }
>
> ```
> class PageState extends State<Page> {
>   List data;
>     Future<List> list() async {
>       Network network = new Network();
>       final String arguments = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as String;
>       print(arguments);
>       var response = await network.list(arguments.toString());
>       print('response>>>>>>');
>       print(response);
>       if (mounted){
>         this.setState(() {
>           data = response;
>         });
>       };
> //      _saving = false;
> //    print('data');
> //    print(data);
>
> //    return "Success!";
>   }
>   @override
>   void initState(){
>     super.initState();
> //    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, this.dados_propostas);
> //    dados_propostas();
>   }
>   @override
>   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
>     this.list();
>     return AlertDialog(
>       title: const Text('Teste'),
>       actions: <Widget>[
>         FlatButton(
>           onPressed: debugDumpApp,
>           child: Row(
>             children: <Widget>[
>               const Icon(
>                 Icons.dvr,
>                 size: 18.0,
>               ),
>               Container(
>                 width: 8.0,
>               ),
>               const Text('DUMP'),
>             ],
>           ),
>         ),
>         FlatButton(
>           onPressed: () {
>             Navigator.pop(context, false);
>           },
>           child: const Text('OK'),
>         ),
>       ],
>     );
>   }
>
> }
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this function:

```
Future<Response> get(String url, String token) async {
    Response response = Response();
    try {
      dio.options.contentType = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";

      dio.options.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer $token";

      response = await dio.get(url);

      return response;
    } on DioError catch (error, stacktrace) {
      print("Exception occured: $error stackTrace: $stacktrace");
      return error.response;
    }
  }
```

Comment: now until print('response>>>>>>');
      print(response);

but, in this code
      if (mounted){
        this.setState(() {
          data = response as Future<String>;
        });
      };
this var data, give a error Unhandled Exception: type 'Response<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Future<String>' in type cast

Comment: It's not giving you error in this function. Now you need to fix your model class object. 
Share your Model class and JSON response.

Comment: Now this ok. Thanks!!!
But, how to use data'[íd'] in Text, see:
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    this.list();
    return AlertDialog(
      title: // how to use data[id] here
     
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          onPressed: debugDumpApp,
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              const Icon(
                Icons.dvr,
                size: 18.0,
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ),
     
      ],
    );
  }

Comment: Now what to do, get a Model class from your JSON. once you will get it, pass JSON response to that class instance. Later use that instance in anywhere in your screen.

Comment: JsonModel _jsonModel = JsonModel.fromJson(response.data);